# Twin Paradox confusing times

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

After reading the article about the Twin Paradox from: Griffiths, David J. (2007) (see pdf on internet)
I got some questions.

There are two frames A and B. 
B moves to the right with velocity $v$.
Star X is to the right of A at a fixed distance $L$. 
Premises: $c=1$, $v=\frac{4}{5}$, $\gamma =\frac{5}{3}$, $L=12$, A and B in Standard Configuration.
According to A in his time, B will arrive at X at $(L,\frac{L}{v}) = (12,15)$

According to B, in his time, he arrives at:
$x' = \gamma(x-vt) = \frac{5}{3}(12-\frac{4}{5}.15) = 0$ 
$t' = \gamma(t - x.\frac{v}{c^2}) = \frac{5}{3}(15-12.\frac{4}{5}) = 9$

Thus at $(x,t)=(0,9)$. OK.

But now the article says:

When B has arrived at X the time in A according to B will be:
$t_B = \gamma(t_A - x_A. \frac{v}{c^2}) = 9 = \frac{5}{3}(t_A - 0) \implies t_A=5.4$

Question1: This confuses me, what is this time? can it be measured by some clock?

For instance, if there is a monitor with a clock (synchronized with A) on X which receives the clock reading from B when B arrives, i guess (and hope) clock X will show 15 but X will receive a reading of 9 from B?

Question2: Is this correct?

If frame B pulled a lattice of clocks along which are all synchronized.
If B reaches X , all these clocks should read 9.

Question3: what reading would a B clock see when passing along A, 5.4?

Comment: This might be better if you focused on one question. If the answer to that clears up the others, great. If not, ask a 2nd question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a spacetime diagram to amplify @JEB's answers.

The rotated graph paper helps us draw the ticks of each leg's light-clock.
The key geometrical feature is that the area of each "light-clock diamond" is equal,
as needed by Lorentz invariance.
You can read off the clock-readings by counting diamonds.
The spacelike diagonal of each diamond is simultaneous according to the observer along the timelike diagonal of that light-clock diamond.

[image: RRGP-robphy-Griffiths-twin]

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: If B arrives at X and has access to A's network of synchronized clocks, then A's clock at X will read 15. This is not a problem for B, since B looks at the network of A's clock and says: they are not synchronized.

Question 2: yes. All of B's clocks throughout space read 9 when he arrives at X.

Question 3: The question is unclear, but I think per Q2, when B arrives at X, his lattice of clocks all read 9, including the clock that is at A (note: A is moving relative to this clock, so A can read 5.4, while B reads 9).

The key to the twin paradox is that when B turns around and becomes B', heading home: the lattice of clocks B is way out of synch. When the new lattice of clock reads "9" at A, A's clock reads 24.6 so that A can age 5.4 more years according to B' during his journey home, resulting in a total age of 30 compared with B+B's 18 years.

The paradox is then the fact when B/B' is at X, A's clock can read 5.4 or 24.6, depending on which way B/B' is moving.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Q1: What do you mean with "they are not synchronized"? they are synchronized for A, but i think if B makes a snapshot of A's clocks he will see they  all show different times, so they are not synchronized for B? (just to make sure for me)


My main point was Q3, so indeed clock B reads 9 when it passes A where clock A would read 5.4.

Comment: @Rob See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity especially the animated diagram near the top of the article. It's not merely that a snapshot by B shows that A's clocks are out of synch in B's frame, they're still out of synch even when you take the light travel times from each of A's clocks to B into account. The animation shows that via the upward moving white line.